# SQL Parent Table to Many Tables

Tags: sql

A friend of mine suggested that we use some new approach on the DB, in which we create a parent table which will home some common columns that we usually use in other tables or mostly all tables, and this parent table will have an identity column (ID) and a type column to tell what does this record link to, and all the tables that are linked to this parent table will have a primary key that is the ID from the parent table and might have some extra columns of its own, but also some tables that link to this parent table will only use most of the columns from the parent not all.
For examble:

***Parent Table:

-ID (Primary Identitiy)
-CreateDateTime
-UpdateDateTime
-Name
-Description
-Location
-Type
-Status
-IsDeleted

***Child Table1: (this one doesn't use the description and location from the parent)

-ParentID (Primary)
-Color
-Size

***Child Table2:

-ParentID (Primary)
-Serial
-Price

And many more tables like the example and as I said some may only use one or two columns from the parent table, its like object oriented in C# where you have some classes inherit from another parent or base class.

Is this even a thing? and is it good?

I fear that this will produce some wasted size in the server

Comment: it's called normalization in database context and it is usually a good thing

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what was done in the 1990s when implementing *Entity Type* and *Entity Subtype* in the *Information Engineering* by James Martin. Actually saves space while helping keep data integrity together, as you would have to use nullable fields in a base table otherwise - or have altogether unconnected tables. Worth pursuing in OLTP environments, a no-no for reporting environments

Answer (score 0):

This kind of table relationship is called a 1-to-1 relationship, since each row in the child table is connected to a single row in the parent table, and since the foreign key is based on the primary key of both tables, it means that each parent row can only be connected to 0 or 1 rows in the child table.

A 1-to-1 relationship based database design might be a good solution to some problems, but not to all.

In fact, Most of the time it's a bad approach.

As a rule of thumb, I would only consider such an approach in a database design If your business entities are actually different variations of the same type - and even then, I would be careful before recommending this approach, because it adds a lot of complicity to all CRUD (Create,Read,Update,Delete) operations.

Consider your example vs a database that contains a table for each item type - with your example, you will have to interact will multiple tables each time you create, read, update or delete an item, while with a table for each type you only need to interact with one table.
That improves not only code simplicity (and as a result - readability and maintainability) but also performance.